# php code for outputting a custom page in my account

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, endpoints

I am trying to figure this out for weeks now. I added some custom endpoints to my woocommerce my-account page. All but one are linked with a shortcode and work fine. One should link to a normal wordpress page, showing it within the my-account page. I don't know how to program php and all it does for now is opening that page on a otherwise empty screen, not within the my-account page.

That's the code I came up with, but the part within the {} must be wrong (as it opens to https://new.holistic-horse-training.com/forum-links):

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_foren_endpoint', 'foren_content' );

function foren_content() {
    return $url = 'https://new.holistic-horse-training.com/konto/forum-links/';
}
```

Could please somebody tell me the correct code for showing that page in the window of my account?
Here is a screenshot of the problem:
https://new.holistic-horse-training.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/content-in-my-account-window-scaled.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Pascale

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

[How to add a new endpoint in woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/200382/how-to-add-a-new-endpoint-in-woocommerce)

Update

In your callback function include your extended template page because output is expected.

ex:

```
function foren_content() {
    include('woocommerce/myaccount/custom-page.php');
}
```

Then inside custom-page.php call the desired content with get_post(ID) or if you have your endpoint registerd in woocommerce settings call it by slug.

The whole process of adding new endpoints is explained in this article with a great example using a class.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039616/woocommerce-assigning-an-endpoint-to-a-custom-template-in-my-account-pages

Personally i would use the class shown in the article because it executes all necessary procedures and you have all the code in one place. I could elaborate on this here but is already explained in posted article.

Depends on the approach and version of woocommerce. The easiest way is to continue current approach. I think your question is a matter of stackoverflow. :)

Hope it helps.
Regards

Comment: Thank you Roman, this is the link I followed and came as far as I did. But I could not find an example of calling a page via its URL and I really, really was searching the www.